# Logging in CXF and RestEasy clients

Tags: logging, jersey, client, cxf, resteasy

this week I was trying Jersey, CXF and RestEasy clients (using JSON) as a standalone application(testing purposes), and I notice something. In Jersey I can enable logs with one line of code:

```
Client client = Client.create();
client.addFilter(new LoggingFilter(System.out));
WebResource webResource = client.resource("http://localhost:8080/IT1/MB1");
....
String output = response.getEntity(String.class);
....
```

Using the LoggingFilter, I get interesting information about the request and/or response in the console as logs.
I find a much a way to do the same on CXF and resteasy, but I only get configurations for log4J and another frameworks, but I can't get that working on an standalone application.
¿Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I answered for CXF here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27871530/how-do-you-get-logging-from-the-cxf-rest-client