# How do you get logging from the CXF Rest Client?

Tags: rest, logging, cxf, cxf-client

This took me quite a long time to figure out.  I'm asking this question so I can answer it for others:

How do you get useful logging info from the CXF Rest Client?  EG: The url, params, payload, response, etc.

Note: This question already exists but it's asking about CXF and Resteasy.  I only want the answer for CXF: [Logging in CXF and RestEasy clients](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19168469/logging-in-cxf-and-resteasy-clients)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's how you do it with CXF:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJaxbJsonProvider;
import org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingInInterceptor;
import org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingOutInterceptor;
import org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.ClientConfiguration;
import org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.WebClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
...
    WebClient client = WebClient.create(endPoint, providers).accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    ClientConfiguration config = WebClient.getConfig(client);
    config.getInInterceptors().add(new LoggingInInterceptor());
    config.getOutInterceptors().add(new LoggingOutInterceptor());
```

Comment: This is still correct, but deprecated, do you know how to do it with features?

Comment: @cocorossello sorry, but I try to avoid this tech now.  I prefer what Spring provides, so I haven't used this in years.

Answer (score 4):

Using the JAX-RS 2.0 client from CXF 3.1.x I am having some trouble getting the LoggingInInterceptor and LoggingOutInterceptor to work.  I changed to use the LoggingFeature as described at http://cxf.apache.org/docs/message-logging.html and it worked first try:

`Client client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder().register(LoggingFeature.class).build()`

Answer (score 0):

You can pass directly an instance of `LoggingFeature` to your client using the appropriate create() method.

```
Response response = WebClient
                .create(baseAddress,
                        Arrays.<Object>asList(Arrays
                                .<Object>asList(new JacksonJsonProvider())),
                        Arrays.<Feature>asList(new LoggingFeature()), null)
                .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).path(path).post(request);
```